# How should I interpret this /proc/cpuinfo data?

Tags: linux, cpu, multi-core, hyper-threading

I'm using Intel Xeon E5-2620 processor. There is something I'm confused about. I'm using Linux and in /proc/cpuinfo it says:

```
model name : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 0 @ 2.00GHz
```

According to the [Intel site](http://ark.intel.com/products/64594), it states that it has 6 cores and 12 threads. What I cannot realize is:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep processor
processor       : 0
processor       : 1
...
processor       : 22
processor       : 23
```

It seems like it has 24 cores or 24 threads, which surprised me. I thought it should be 6 or 12. Why there are 24 processors in `/proc/cpuinfo`? How should I interpret this data?

Comment: These might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019129/cpu-ordering-in-linux-with-hyper-threading and http://serverfault.com/questions/227920/is-it-possible-to-tell-which-cpus-are-hyperthreads-of-the-same-core

Comment: That looks like the correct results for a system with 2 CPUs (processor chips) each with 6 cores, each core with 2 threads. Each thread is presented to the OS as a processor.

Comment: Thanks. It seems that it has 2 physical CPUs. Actually cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "physical id" | sort | uniq states that
physical id     : 0
physical id     : 1 which means it has 2 CPUs.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are two physical CPUs with 6 cores. Because each core has 2 threads the total number of logical processors is 2*6*6 = 24.